# Godaddy.com hosting and email

Tags: php

I have the following code for sending emails from my website.
After migrating to Godaddy.com my site cant send any email when required. The code is the following:

```
public function sendEmail($mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message)
{
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
/* line 124 */ return (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) ? true : false;  /* line 
124 */
    }
```

Please note that before changing hosting servers we did not have any problems with email.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Any error messages?  Did you contact GoDaddy tech support?  Have you thought of using a hosting provider whose CEO doesn't kill elephants?

Comment: I am glad someone has a sense of humor on SO!

Answer (score 2):

Use port 587 as advised in this article: http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/